# ng-messages dont reset when resetting the form

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I have a big problem in my form when I try to reset it everything is reset except the ng messages. I tried everything but nothing worked. I don't know why

Here is my form:

```
<md-content layout-padding>
   <form name="projectForm">
      <div layout="row">
         <md-input-container flex="50">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input required name="clientName" ng-model="project.clientName" ng-focus="">
         </md-input-container>
         <md-input-container flex="50">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input required type="email" name="clientEmail" ng-model="newEmployee.email"
               minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" />
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.clientEmail.$error" role="alert" ng-show="message">
               <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                  Your email must be between 10 and 100 characters long and look like an e-mail address.
               </div>
            </div>
         </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <div layout="row">
         <md-input-container flex="50">
            <label>Mobile</label>
            <input required name="clientName" ng-model="newEmployee.mobile">
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.clientName.$error" ng-show="message">
               <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
         </md-input-container>
         <md-input-container flex="50">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input required name="clientName" ng-model="newEmployee.address">
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.clientName.$error" ng-show="message">
               <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
         </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <md-input-container class="md-block">
         <label>Description</label>
         <input md-maxlength="30" required md-no-asterisk name="description" ng-model="newEmployee.description">
         <div ng-messages="projectForm.description.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The description must be less than 30 characters long.</div>
         </div>
      </md-input-container>
      <div>
         <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Submit</md-button>
         <md-button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
      </div>
   </form>
</md-content>
```

and here is my reset function in the controller

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.projectForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.projectForm.$setValidity();
    $scope.projectForm.$setUntouched();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you reset by just setting `$scope.projectForm = {}`? Give it a try and see if the validation messages do not disappear.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue with angular-material 1.1.1 and angularjs 1.5.8. Did you finally find a solution to this?